# How is Levenshtein Distance calculated on Simplified Chinese characters?

Tags: python, string, unicode, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

I have 2 queries:

```
    query1:你好世界
    query2:你好
```

When i run this code using the python library Levenshtein:

```
from Levenshtein import distance, hamming, median
lev_edit_dist = distance(query1,query2)
print lev_edit_dist
```

I get an output of 12. 
Now the question is how is the value 12 derived?

Because in terms of strokes difference, theres definitely more than 12.

Comment: are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: i am using python 2.7

Comment: For Chinese characters, it would really make sense to move to Python 3. All sorts of sticking issues re. Unicode characters have been ironed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to its [documentation](https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html#Levenshtein-distance), it supports unicode:

> It supports both normal and Unicode strings, but can't mix them, all
>   arguments to a function (method) have to be of the same type (or its
>   subclasses).

You need to make sure the Chinese characters are in unicode though:

```
In [1]: from Levenshtein import distance, hamming, median

In [2]: query1 = '你好世界'

In [3]: query2 = '你好'

In [4]: print distance(query1,query2)
6

In [5]: print distance(query1.decode('utf8'),query2.decode('utf8'))
2
```